# Does Chrome have to be running in order for Gmail to handle mailto links?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, mailto

I noticed that Google Chrome [has a feature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24284/how-do-i-get-gmail-to-ask-me-to-be-a-mailto-handler-again) which let's Gmail handle `mailto:` links. I'm wondering whether or not Chrome has to be running on the computer in order for this to work or not.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some testing, it seems that Chrome **does not** need to be running in order for it to handle `mailto:` links. It will launch Chrome and open up a new tab to the `mailto:` address, which then gets redirected to Gmail.

On Mac OS X, this works because Chrome changes itself to be the default mail client.