# How do I get Google Inbox to ask me to be a mailto handler?

Tags: google-chrome, inbox-by-gmail, mailto

Google Inbox doesn't appear to offer to handle `mailto:` links as [Gmail does](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33951/15338).

Is there a way to enable this in Google Inbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `Gmail` option under the left hand menu in Inbox, which can be accessed using the [hamburger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) in the top left.

Once in Gmail you can enable it per [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33951/15338).

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Go to https://inbox.google.com and click the diamond-shaped icon to the right of Chrome's address bar (omnibox). Then choose Allow and Finished:

[image: Chrome content handler dialog]

Comment: No diamonds for me.

Comment: @glenviewjeff I think I just managed to fix it. I went into gmail and set that up as the mailto-manager using the diamonds. When going back to Inbox the diamonds were there again and I could re-set it as the mailto-manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FireFox, Google doesn't present the handler-registration interface. However, all is not lost!

Open the developer tools with **<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>**, and click the **Console** tab:

[image]

Then, copy-and-paste the following JavaScript snippet:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto"
 , "https://inbox.google.com/?mailto=%s"
 , "Inbox")
```

[image]

You should see a banner appear at the top of your Inbox window, asking if you want to allow Inbox to become a registered handler for `mailto:` links. Click ‘allow.’

Next, you'll have to select Inbox as the desired handler inside FireFox itself,

[image]

… and finally, figure out a way to convince macOS to then select FireFox as the system-wide handler for `mailto:` links. I keep the venerable-but-still-functioning (at least, as of the 10.14 “Mojave” beta, anyway) [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) PrefPane installed for exactly this purpose:

[image]

Congratulations! You can test it out in the terminal, with a command like `open 'mailto:test@test.com'`. Go forth, and verily shalt thou `sendmail`!

Answer (score -3):

You can try and set gmail to redirect to inbox in the inbox's definitions panel /Other

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean - could you rewrite your answer, and perhaps include a screenshot?

Comment: How would that handle 'mailto:' links?